# Standalone Code-Block Works, But Function Call W/ Same Code Does Not (C Program)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, function-calls

I have a connect 4 game that I am making. Everything works, and when you load the game on startup with

"./a.out -l"

if this chunk of code below is in the conditional that checks for that flag

```
        int r, c, i;

        // this loads the game settings into game
        FILE *fp = fopen("gameSave.txt", "r");
        fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d %c", &num_rows, &num_columns, &length_to_win, &player);
        fscanf(fp, "\n\n");

        aPtr = malloc(num_rows * sizeof(char*));

        for (i = 0; i < num_rows; i++){
            aPtr[i] = malloc(num_columns * sizeof (char));
        }

        for (r = 0; r < num_rows; r++) {
            for (c = 0; c < num_columns; c++) {
                fscanf(fp, " %c", &aPtr[r][c]);
                printf("%c ", aPtr[r][c]);
            }
            fscanf(fp, "\n");
            printf("\n");
        }

        printf("Game Loaded\n");
        fclose(fp);
```

it works just fine and after this conditional I call the function printBoard() and I get the following output

```
Starting Game
0 1 0 9 9 9 9 
0 1 9 9 9 9 9 
0 1 9 9 9 9 9 
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 
Game Loaded
*********************
   Starting Board   
*********************



------ Connect *Four ------
Connect X Command Line Game
&&===========================&&
||   |   |   |   |   |   |   ||
||   |   |   |   |   |   |   ||
||   |   |   |   |   |   |   ||
||   |   |   |   |   |   |   ||
|| X | O |   |   |   |   |   ||
|| X | O |   |   |   |   |   ||
|| X | O | X |   |   |   |   ||
&&===========================&&
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7  

Player: 2s Turn


Enter Column # To Place Token
```

I am then able to play the game as expected and everything works. However, if I put that same chunk of code into a function like the one below

```
void loadGame(int num_rows, int num_columns, int length_to_win, char player, char **aPtr){

        int r, c, i;

        // this loads the game settings into game
        FILE *fp = fopen("gameSave.txt", "r");
        fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d %c", &num_rows, &num_columns, &length_to_win, &player);
        fscanf(fp, "\n\n");

        aPtr = malloc(num_rows * sizeof(char*));

        for (i = 0; i < num_rows; i++){
            aPtr[i] = malloc(num_columns * sizeof (char));
        }

        for (r = 0; r < num_rows; r++) {
            for (c = 0; c < num_columns; c++) {
                fscanf(fp, " %c", &aPtr[r][c]);
                printf("%c ", aPtr[r][c]);
            }
            fscanf(fp, "\n");
            printf("\n");
        }

        printf("Game Loaded\n");
        printBoard(num_rows, num_columns, aPtr);
        fclose(fp);

}
```

and then comment out that same code in the conditional leaving only the following

```
        load = true;

        loadGame(num_rows, num_columns, length_to_win, player, aPtr);
```

it gives me this output

```
Starting Game
0 1 0 9 9 9 9 
0 1 9 9 9 9 9 
0 1 9 9 9 9 9 
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 
Game Loaded
*********************
   Starting Board   
*********************



------ Connect *Four ------
Connect X Command Line Game
&&===========================&&
||   |   |   |   |   |   |   ||
|Segmentation fault: 11
```

and I'm not exactly sure why... this means that in the for-loop where the visualization of the board is created there is some kind of problem... could it be a scope issue perhaps (maybe with number of rows or columns)? the function that creates the board looks like this

```
void printBoard(int num_rows, int num_columns, char **aPtr) {
    int row, col; 
    int r, c;

    printf("\n");
    puts("------ Connect *Four ------");
    puts("Connect X Command Line Game");

    // for fancy top of board frame
    printf("&&");
    for(col = 1; col < num_columns; col++) {
        printf("====");
    }
    printf("===");
    printf("&&\n");

    // for the rows/columns of the board
    for(row = num_rows - 1; row >= 0; row--){
        printf("|");
        for(col = 0; col < num_columns; col++){
            if(aPtr[row][col] == '0') {
                printf("| X ");
            }
            else if(aPtr[row][col] == '1') {
                printf("| O ");
            }
            else {
                printf("|   ");
            }      
        }
        puts("||");
    }

   // for fancy bottom of board frame
    printf("&&");
    for(col = 1; col < num_columns; col++) {
        printf("====");
    }
    printf("===");
    printf("&&\n");
    printf("  ");

    // if the board is less than 100 columns,
    // print the column number (for readability)
    if (col < 100){
        for(col = 0; col < num_columns; col++) {
            if (col < 10) {
                printf(" %d  ", col + 1);
            }
            else {
                printf("%d  ", col + 1);
            }
        }
        puts("\n");
    }
}
```

Any advice as to why this is happening would be much appreciated, if you want to run the code for yourself, all the code is below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdbool.h>



// This is where the default board gets created
// The reasoning behind setting all values = '9'
// is that when a player places their piece on the board
// the location of that piece will then become their
// player number, which is used accordingly when
// saving and loading the game
void initialize(int num_rows, int num_cols, char **aPtr) {
    int r, c;

    for (r = 0; r < num_rows; r++) {
        for (c = 0; c < num_cols; c++) {
            aPtr[r][c] = '9';
        }
    }
}
// end of initialize



// this is where the board gets printed according to its
// state (whether default-starting, game in progress, or
// loaded game). It looks at the values of the 2D array
// and depending on whether or not they are default 9's or
// player numbers, prints out the appropriate illustration
void printBoard(int num_rows, int num_columns, char **aPtr) {
    int row, col; 

    printf("\n");
    puts("------ Connect *Four ------");
    puts("Connect X Command Line Game");

    // for fancy top of board frame
    printf("&&");
    for(col = 1; col < num_columns; col++) {
        printf("====");
    }
    printf("===");
    printf("&&\n");

    // for the rows/columns of the board
    for(row = num_rows - 1; row >= 0; row--){
        printf("|");
        for(col = 0; col < num_columns; col++){
            if(aPtr[row][col] == '0') {
                printf("| X ");
            }
            else if(aPtr[row][col] == '1') {
                printf("| O ");
            }
            else {
                printf("|   ");
            }      
        }
        puts("||");
    }

   // for fancy bottom of board frame
    printf("&&");
    for(col = 1; col < num_columns; col++) {
        printf("====");
    }
    printf("===");
    printf("&&\n");
    printf("  ");

    // if the board is less than 100 columns,
    // print the column number (for readability)
    if (col < 100){
        for(col = 0; col < num_columns; col++) {
            if (col < 10) {
                printf(" %d  ", col + 1);
            }
            else {
                printf("%d  ", col + 1);
            }
        }
        puts("\n");
    }
}
// end of printBoard



// This is a global variable used to signify the state of
// whether or not there is a winner
char winnerVal = '0';


// this checks if the board is full or not to check for a win or tie
int checkFullBoard(int num_rows, int num_columns, char **aPtr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < num_columns; i++) {
        if (aPtr[num_rows - 1][i] == '9') {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}


// this checks for the first available location within a column for players
// to place their pieces, if there is no available space in a column, it returns
// -1 which signals the player that they must adjust their placement
int checkForColHeight(int num_rows, int num_columns, int column, char **aPtr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < num_rows; i++) {
        if (aPtr[i][column] == '9') {
            return i;
        }     
    }
    return -1;
}


// this is where a token is placed at an appropriate position if it is within the 
// allowances of the game
int place_token(char player, int column, int num_rows, int num_columns, char **aPtr) {

  /*Check for invalid Parameters*/
    if(column > (num_columns - 1) || column < 0 || (player != '1' && player != '0') 
    || num_columns <= 0 || num_rows <= 0) {;
        return -1;
    }  

    int firstOpenRow = checkForColHeight(num_rows, num_columns, column, aPtr);
        if (firstOpenRow == -1) { 
            return -1;
        }
        else {
            aPtr[firstOpenRow][column] = player;
            return 1;
        }
}


// this is where a check for a win occurs. Essentially until it finds a line long enough to win it'll return negative
char checkForSeries(int direction, int num_rows, int num_columns, int length_to_win, int r, int c, char **aPtr) {
    switch (direction) {

        /*Horizontal*/
        case 0:           
            for (int i = 1; i < length_to_win; i++) {
                if (aPtr[r][c] == '9' ) {
                    return '2';
                }
                else if (aPtr[r][c] != aPtr[r][c + i] ) {
                    return '2';
                }
            }
            return aPtr[r][c];
            break;      

        /*Vertical*/
        case 1: 
            for (int i = 1; i < length_to_win; i++) {
                if (aPtr[r][c] == '9' ) {
                    return '2';
                }
                else if (aPtr[r][c] != aPtr[r + i][c] ) {
                    return '2';
                }
            }
            return aPtr[r][c];     
            break;

        /*Left Diag*/
        case 2:
            for (int i = 1; i < length_to_win; i++) {
                if (aPtr[r][c] == '9' ) {
                    return '2';
                }
                else if (aPtr[r][c] != aPtr[r + i][c - i] ) {
                    return '2';
                }
            }
            return aPtr[r][c]; 
            break;

        /*Right Diag*/
        case 3:
            for (int i = 1; i < length_to_win; i++) {
                if (aPtr[r][c] == '9' ) {
                    return '2';
                }
                else if (aPtr[r][c] != aPtr[r + i][c + i] ) {
                    return '2';
                }
            }
            return aPtr[r][c]; 
            break;    

        return '2';
    }

    return '0';
}
// end of checkForSeries


// checks for any horizontal wins
int checkHorizontal(int num_rows, int num_columns, int length_to_win, char **aPtr){  
    int r, c;
    for (r = 0; r < num_rows; r++) {    
        for(c = 0; c < num_columns - (length_to_win - 1); c++) {      
            char winner = checkForSeries(0, num_rows, num_columns, length_to_win, r, c, aPtr);
            if(winner != '2') {
                winnerVal = winner;       
                return 1;
            }     
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

// checks for any vertical wins
int checkVertical(int num_rows, int num_columns, int length_to_win, char **aPtr){  
    int r, c;
    for (c = 0; c < num_columns; c++) {   
        for(r = 0; r < num_rows - (length_to_win - 1); r++) {     
            char winner = checkForSeries(1, num_rows, num_columns, length_to_win, r, c, aPtr);
            if(winner != '2') {
                winnerVal = winner;       
                return 1;
            }     
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

// checks for any left-diagonal wins
int checkDiagLeft(int num_rows, int num_columns, int length_to_win, char **aPtr){  
    int r, c;
    for (r = 0; r < num_rows - (length_to_win - 1); r++) {    
        for(c = num_columns - 1; c > (length_to_win - 2); c--) {      
            char winner = checkForSeries(2, num_rows, num_columns, length_to_win, r, c, aPtr);
            if(winner != '2') {
                winnerVal = winner;       
            return 1;
            }     
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

// checks for any right-diagonal wins
int checkDiagRight(int num_rows, int num_columns, int length_to_win, char **aPtr){
    int r, c;
    for (r = 0; r < num_rows - (length_to_win - 1); r++) {
        for(c = 0; c < num_columns - (length_to_win - 1); c++) {
            char winner = checkForSeries(3, num_rows, num_columns, length_to_win, r, c, aPtr);
            if(winner != '2') {
                winnerVal = winner;
                return 1;
            }     
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


/*Return the integer representation of the winning player, -1 if a tie or error*/
char winner(int num_rows, int num_columns, int length_to_win, char **aPtr) {
    if (length_to_win <= 0 || length_to_win > num_columns || num_columns <= 0 || num_rows <= 0) {
        return '2';
    }

    if (checkHorizontal(num_rows, num_columns, length_to_win, aPtr) 
        || checkVertical(num_rows, num_columns, length_to_win, aPtr)
        || checkDiagLeft(num_rows, num_columns, length_to_win, aPtr)
        || checkDiagRight(num_rows, num_columns, length_to_win, aPtr)) {
        return winnerVal; 
    }

    if(checkFullBoard(num_rows, num_columns, aPtr)) {
        return '2';
    }
    return '2';
}


char **loadGame(int num_rows, int num_columns, int length_to_win, char player, char **aPtr){

            int r, c, i;

            // this loads the game settings into game
            FILE *fp = fopen("gameSave.txt", "r");
            fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d %c", &num_rows, &num_columns, &length_to_win, &player);
            fscanf(fp, "\n\n");

            aPtr = malloc(num_rows * sizeof(char*));

            for (i = 0; i < num_rows; i++){
                aPtr[i] = malloc(num_columns * sizeof (char));
            }

            for (r = 0; r < num_rows; r++) {
                for (c = 0; c < num_columns; c++) {
                    fscanf(fp, " %c", aPtr[r][c]);
                    printf("%c ", aPtr[r][c]);
                }
                fscanf(fp, "\n");
                printf("\n");
            }

            return aPtr;
            printf("Game Loaded\n");
            fclose(fp);

}


// END OF FUNCTIONS
// *******************************************************************************************************
// *******************************************************************************************************
// START OF MAIN METHOD


int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    int num_rows = 7;
    int num_columns = 7;
    int length_to_win = 4;
    int i, index, attmpt;
    char **aPtr;
    char player = '0';
    bool load = false;

    printf("Starting Game\n");  



    // this loop checks for command line arguments and sets game variables accordingly.
    for(index = 0; index < argc; ++index) {

        if ( strncmp( argv[index], "-h", 5) == 0 ) {
            num_rows =atoi(argv[index + 1]);
        }
        if ( strncmp( argv[index], "-height", 5) == 0 ) {
            num_rows =atoi(argv[index + 1]);
        }
        if ( strncmp( argv[index], "-w", 5) == 0 ) {
            num_columns = atoi(argv[index + 1]);
        }
        if ( strncmp( argv[index], "-width", 5) == 0 ) {
            num_columns = atoi(argv[index + 1]);
        }
        if ( strncmp( argv[index], "-s", 5) == 0 ) {
            num_rows = atoi(argv[index + 1]);
            num_columns = atoi(argv[index + 1]);
        }
        if ( strncmp( argv[index], "-square", 5) == 0 ) {
            num_rows = atoi(argv[index + 1]);
            num_columns = atoi(argv[index + 1]);
        }
        if ( strncmp( argv[index], "-c", 5) == 0 ) {
            length_to_win = atoi(argv[index + 1]);
        }
        if ( strncmp( argv[index], "-connect", 5) == 0 ) {
            length_to_win = atoi(argv[index + 1]);
        }
        if ( strncmp( argv[index], "-l", 5) == 0 ) {

            load = true;

             aPtr = loadGame(num_rows, num_columns, length_to_win, player, aPtr);
            // int r, c;

            // this loads the game settings into game
            // FILE *fp = fopen("gameSave.txt", "r");
            // fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d %c", &num_rows, &num_columns, &length_to_win, &player);
            // fscanf(fp, "\n\n");

            // aPtr = malloc(num_rows * sizeof(char*));

            // for (i = 0; i < num_rows; i++){
            //     aPtr[i] = malloc(num_columns * sizeof (char));
            // }

            // for (r = 0; r < num_rows; r++) {
            //     for (c = 0; c < num_columns; c++) {
            //         fscanf(fp, " %c", &aPtr[r][c]);
            //         printf("%c ", aPtr[r][c]);
            //     }
            //     fscanf(fp, "\n");
            //     printf("\n");
            // }

            // printf("Game Loaded\n");
            // fclose(fp);
        }
    }



    // these conditionals check for valid board size
    if (num_rows <= 2 || num_columns <= 2 ){
        printf("%s\n","You entered a width or length that was invalid." );
    }
    if (length_to_win <= 2 || length_to_win > (num_rows - 1)) {
        printf("%s\n","You entered a winning length that was invalid." );
    }


    // if the game isn't loaded upon execution, the load it normally
    if (load == false) {
        aPtr = malloc(num_rows * sizeof(char*));

        for (i = 0; i < num_rows; i++){
           aPtr[i] = malloc(num_columns * sizeof (char));
        }

        initialize(num_rows, num_columns, aPtr);
    }


    printf("%s\n", "*********************");
    printf("%s\n", "   Starting Board   ");
    printf("%s\n", "*********************");
    puts("\n");

    printBoard(num_rows, num_columns, aPtr);

    printf("Player: %cs Turn\n", player + 1); 
    puts("\n");



    // this is the loop that runs while the game is in progress 
    // it continually checks for winners, full boards, valid moves, etc. 
    while(1) {       

        // prompts the user to select which column they want their piece to be placed
        // -1 on the temp because the first column is technically 0 so if a player
        // wants to place their piece in column "1", it'll be placed at index[0] accordingly
        printf("%s\n", "Enter Column # To Place Token"); 
        int column;
        char temp[20];
        char temp2[20];       
        scanf("%s", temp); 

        if (strncmp (temp, "save", 5) == 0){
            int r, c;

            // this writes the game settings to a file called "gameSave.txt"
            // if the file doesn't exist it just creates it
            int *rows = &num_rows;
            int *cols = &num_columns;
            int *len = &length_to_win;
            char *play = &player;
            FILE *fp = fopen("gameSave.txt", "w+");
            fprintf(fp, "%d ", *rows);
            fprintf(fp, "%d ", *cols);
            fprintf(fp, "%d ", *len);
            fprintf(fp, "%c ", *play);
            fprintf(fp, "\n\n");

            // this loop saves the actual board state to the file
            for (r = 0; r < num_rows; r++) {
                for (c = 0; c < num_columns; c++) {
                    fprintf(fp, "%c ", aPtr[r][c]);
                }
                fprintf(fp, "\n");
            }

            printf("Game Saved\n");
            fclose(fp);
        }

        if (strncmp (temp, "load", 5) == 0){
            int r, c;

            // this loads the game settings into game
            FILE *fp = fopen("gameSave.txt", "r");
            fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d %c", &num_rows, &num_columns, &length_to_win, &player);
            fscanf(fp, "\n\n");

            // this creates space for the loaded game
            aPtr = malloc(num_rows * sizeof(char*));
            for (i = 0; i < num_rows; i++){
                aPtr[i] = malloc(num_columns * sizeof (char));
            }

            // this fills the board with the saved game-data
            for (r = 0; r < num_rows; r++) {
                for (c = 0; c < num_columns; c++) {
                    fscanf(fp, " %c", &aPtr[r][c]);
                }
                fscanf(fp, "\n");
            }

            printf("Game Loaded\n");
            fclose(fp);
        }


        column = atoi(temp) - 1;
        attmpt = place_token(player, column, num_rows, num_columns, aPtr);

        if ((column < 0 || column > (num_columns - 1)) && (strncmp (temp, "save", 5) != 0) && (strncmp (temp, "load", 5) != 0)) {
            printf("%s\n","You entered a column that was invalid. Please try again." );
            continue;
        }

        if (attmpt != 1 && (strncmp (temp, "save", 5) != 0) && (strncmp (temp, "load", 5) != 0)) {
            printf("%s\n","This row is already full. Please try again." );
            continue;
        }

        printf("%s\n", "************************");
        printf("%s\n", "      Board Updated     ");
        printf("%s\n", "************************");  
        puts("\n");  
        printBoard(num_rows, num_columns, aPtr);
        puts("\n");



        if ((strncmp (temp, "save", 5) != 0) && (strncmp (temp, "load", 5) != 0)) {
            if (checkFullBoard(num_rows, num_columns, aPtr)) {
                printf("%s\n","This game is a tie. Thanks for Playing.\n");
                return 0;
            }
        }


        // this if-statement will constantly be run while the game progresses, 
        // meaning that winner will be called at every turn and 
        // all of the win conditions will be checked until a winner is found
        char isWin = winner(num_rows, num_columns, length_to_win, aPtr);
        if(isWin != '2') {
            printf("Player: %c is the winner! Thanks for Playing.\n", isWin + 1);
            printf("Play again? (enter 'y' to continue)\n");
            printf("Or load a previously saved game with 'load'\n");
            scanf("%s", temp2);

            // if the player wants to play again, clear the board for a new game
            // and start over
            if (strncmp (temp2, "y", 5) == 0){
                initialize(num_rows, num_columns, aPtr);
                printBoard(num_rows, num_columns, aPtr);
                puts("\n");
            }
            if (strncmp (temp2, "load", 5) == 0) {
                int r, c;

                // this loads the game settings into game
                FILE *fp = fopen("gameSave.txt", "r");
                fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d %c", &num_rows, &num_columns, &length_to_win, &player);
                fscanf(fp, "\n\n");

                aPtr = malloc(num_rows * sizeof(char*));

                for (i = 0; i < num_rows; i++){
                    aPtr[i] = malloc(num_columns * sizeof (char));
                }

                for (r = 0; r < num_rows; r++) {
                    for (c = 0; c < num_columns; c++) {
                        fscanf(fp, " %c", &aPtr[r][c]);
                        printf("%c ", aPtr[r][c]);
                    }
                    fscanf(fp, "\n");
                    printf("\n");
                }

                printf("Game Loaded\n");
                puts("\n");
                printBoard(num_rows, num_columns, aPtr);
                fclose(fp);
            }

            else {
                printf("Game over, goodbye!\n");
                return 0;
            }
        }

        // if a winner is not found then this if/else will continue to switch
        // between players at the end of each turn
        if ((strncmp (temp, "save", 5) != 0) && (strncmp (temp, "load", 5) != 0) && (strncmp (temp2, "y", 5) != 0)) {
            if (player == '1') {
                player = '0';
            }
            else {
                player = '1';
            }
        }
        memset(temp, 0, sizeof temp);
        memset(temp2, 0, sizeof temp2);

        printf("Player: %cs Turn\n", player +1);
    } // end of while loop

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `void loadGame(...., char **aPtr){` --> `void loadGame(...., char ***aPtr){` then call `loadGame(......, &aPtr);` or `char **loadGame(.......){` then `return aPtr;`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I went ahead and changed the function call to ....&aPtr
and the function parameter to ***aPtr
but when I do this I get the following errors

test.c:305:39: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char **' [-Wformat]
                    fscanf(fp, " %c", &aPtr[r][c]);
                                 ~~   ^~~~~~~~~~~
test.c:306:35: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'char *' [-Wformat]
                    printf("%c ", aPtr[r][c]);
                            ~~    ^~~~~~~~~~
                            %s

Comment: Tooo big code. Did you use debugger?

Comment: same problem as [previous Q](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42590796/segmentation-fault-when-creating-connect-4-board-c-program)

Comment: Too much code, please read this: [MCVE].

Comment: `fscanf(fp, " %c", &aPtr[r][c])` --> `fscanf(fp, " %c", &(*aPtr)[r][c])` , `printf("%c ", aPtr[r][c]);` --> `printf("%c ", (*aPtr)[r][c]);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [segmentation fault when creating connect 4 board c program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42590796/segmentation-fault-when-creating-connect-4-board-c-program)

Comment: Change is less, opt2) `char **loadGame(.......){ char **aPtr;` ... `return aPtr;`. this call such as `aPtr = loadGame(.......);`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I changed the full code section of the question to show the changes I made (I went with opt2). I can see what you're saying but with these new changes all I get is a "starting game" and a seg-fault

Comment: `fscanf(fp, " %c", aPtr[r][c]);` --> `fscanf(fp, " %c", &aPtr[r][c]);`. Also `loadGame(num_rows, num_columns,...`num_rows, num_columns`  can't update too.

Comment: `return aPtr;
            printf("Game Loaded\n");
            fclose(fp);` --> `fclose(fp); printf("Game Loaded\n"); return aPtr;`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY yeah, I understand now. I'll just set the game setting values before the function call in the same way the function does itself, at least this way I'm saving some lines of code and have working function call. Thank you!

Comment: Please, accept my answer if it was satisfactory and helped you, else, tell me how can I help you more!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your question is a little bit clumsy, check out the guide @Michael provided in the comments.

Now, from what I've understood, the problem is that you're passing the value of the variables when calling the function loadGame(...) instead of a reference to them. The variables num_rows, num_columns, length_to_win and the others are not being modified by the function.

Check out this example:

```
void wrong (int a, int b, int c) {

    a = 1;
    b = 2;
    c = 3;

}

void correct (int *a, int *b, int *c) {

    *a = 1;
    *b = 2;
    *c = 3;

}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int a, b, c;

    a = b = c = -1;

    /* 
     Not modified after function call.
     */

    wrong(a, b, c);

    printf("wrong a: %i b: %i c: %i\n", a, b, c);

    /*
     Modified after function call.
     */

    correct(&a, &b, &c);

    printf("correct a: %i b: %i c: %i\n", a, b, c);

    return 0;
}
```